# Mount CIFS/SMB file share with S4U2Proxy?

Tags: kerberos, cifs, smbfs

Is there any way to mount a CIFS/SMB file share by authenticating with S4U2Proxy? I need a middleware service to mount a file share and it has a Kerberos ticket from the user who logged into it. I've gotten as far as having a proxy ticket for the file share, but mount.cifs doesn't allow it.

AFAICT from looking at the source code, mount.cifs has no support for S4U2Proxy (i.e., Resource-Based Kerberos Constrained Delegation). Is there any cifs mounting mechanism that supports this?

Edit: The middleware does not have a TGT, only a service ticket.

Comment: Does the service have a TGT or just a service specific ticket e.g. `HTTP/server.example.com`?

Comment: Only service ticket. (I clarified the question.)